# Aggregation or Map Reduce to create normalized 'Unique Paying Users Per Vendor'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am trying to created a report for Unique Paying Users Per Vendor using Map Reduce or the Aggregation Framework in Mongodb. The only catch is that the totals need to be normalized such each user contribute a total of 1 across all of the vendors he/she has purchased from. For example

```js
{
   "account": "abc",
   "vendor": "amazon",
},
{
   "account": "abc",
   "vendor": "overstock",
},
{
   "account": "ccc",
   "vendor": "overstock",
}
```

would produce

```js
{
   "vendor": "amazon",
   "total" : 0.5
},
{ 
   "vendor": "overstock",
   "total": 1.5
}
```

Here we see the user 'abc' made two purchases and contributes equally to both vendors. We also see that summing up vendors totals would be equal to our unique paying users.

My naive approach to performs this aggregation in four steps.

```js
1. For each user, store number of purchases by vendor in a map.
2. For each user, sum up total purchases and divide each vendor purchases by total.
3. Perform an additive merge of each users normalized purchase map into a final vendor map.
```

This approach works with smaller data sets but is slow and runs out of memory on larger sets.

Using the Aggregation framework, I've figured out how to calculate the total users but in a normalized method.

```js
agg = this.db.aggregate(
[
    {
        $group :
        {
            _id :
            {
                vendor : '$vendor',
                user : '$account'
            },
            total :
            {
                $sum : 1
            }
        }
    }
]);

var transformed = {};
for( var index in agg.result)
{
    var entry = agg.result[index];

    var vendor= entry._id.vendor;
    if(!transformed[vendor])
    {
        transformed[vendor] = 0;
    }
    transformed[vendor] += 1;
}
```

How can I restructure this query to normalize the users totals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this which can apply to either the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) or the [`.mapReduce()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) methods respectively, and they of course vary in efficiency which is relative to the overall size of your data.

Firstly using aggregate, you would need to get the totals per "vendor" much as you have done, but then you would need the overall total per user in order to work out your percentages. So mileage may vary on how efficient the grouping operation is considering we are going to have to create and [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) arrays:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "account": "$account", "vendor": "$vendor" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.account",
        "purch": { "$push": { "vendor": "$_id.vendor", "count": "$count" } },
        "total": { "$sum": "$count" },
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$purch" },
    { "$project": {
        "vendor": "$purch.vendor",
        "total": { 
            "$divide": [ "$purch.count", "$total" ]
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$vendor",
        "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
    }}
])
```

---

The mapReduce approach would have to be run in two step, first reducing the response to vendors by user and then afterwards down to the vendor:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
        emit(
            this.account,
            {
                "data": [{
                    "vendor": this.vendor,
                    "count": 1,
                }],
                "total": 1,
                "seen": false
            }
        );
    },
    function (key,values) {

        var reduced = { data: [], total: 0, seen: true };

        values.forEach(function(value) {
            value.data.forEach(function(data) {
                var index = -1;
                for (var i = 0; i <=reduced.data.length-1; i++) {

                    if ( reduced.data[i].vendor == data.vendor ) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ( index == -1 ) {
                    reduced.data.push(data);
                } else {
                    if (!value.seen)
                        reduced.data[index].count += data.count;
                }
            });
        });

        reduced.data.map(function(x) {
            reduced.total += x.count;
        });

        return reduced;
    },
    { 
        "out": { "replace": "output" },
        "finalize": function (key,value) {

            var result = {
                data: []
            };

            result.data = value.data.map(function(x) {
                var res = { };
                res["vendor"] = x.vendor;
                res["total"] = x.count / value.total;
                return res;
            });

            return result;
        }
    }
)
```

And the second part on the output:

```js
db.output.mapReduce(
    function () {
        this.value.data.forEach(function(data){
            emit( data.vendor, data.total );
        });
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum( values );
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

So it depends on the size of your data. The mapReduce approach will be slower and requires the output to a collection and then running the aggregation again.

On the other hand the aggregation framework approach should run faster in general but depending on how large that vendor array can get per user it can slow things down.

Comment: Please see my response below. I added some code. Thank for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response Neil Lunn's answer above.  After some thought yesterday, I came to the same realization as you did that the aggregation would have to be a multi step process if in map reduce.  I like your answer as it uses map reduce to write to a collection which in a larger data set would be required. I'll also try out the .aggregrate() method for performance. Interesting to note that the new aggregation framework in Mongo 2.6 also has this 'out' feature.

The solution I ended up with is the following (which works with our data set).

```
1. use aggregation framework to calculate purchases per account.
2. convert this result into a map for fast access
3. perform map reduce on collection making user of the 'scope' field to pass in the account total map we built in step 2.
```

The code looks similar to this.

```
var agg = this.db.aggregate(
[
    {
        $group :
        {
            _id :
            {
                user : '$account'
            },
            total :
            {
                $sum : 1
            }
        }
    }
]);

var accountMap = {};
for( var index in agg.result)
{
    var entry = agg.result[index];
    addToMap(accountMap, entry._id.user, entry.total);
}

delete agg; // free up memory?

var mapFunction = function()
{
    var key = this.vendor;

    // create normalized total for the vendor based on the users purchases. 
    var value = 1 / accountMap[this.account];

    emit(key, value);
};

var reduceFunction = function(key, values)
{
    return(Array.sum(values));
};

var res = this.db.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction,
{
    out :
    {
        inline : 1
    },
    scope :
    {
        'accountMap' : accountMap
    }
});

delete accountMap;

var transformed = {};

for( var index in res.results)
{
    transformed[entry._id] = entry.value;
}
```